# PHP Add new once element in array and remove last once

Tags: php, arrays

I want to always keep three element in array. So, I want if new element is added in array then oldest element will remove from array and Re-index array. Which is the best and fast way to make it?

This is my first array

```
$foo = array(

    'when', // [0]
    'whom', // [1]
    'what' // [2]

);
```

If new element "how" added, I want to modify like below.

```
$foo = array(

    'how', // [0]
    'whom', // [1]
    'what' // [2]

);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has many built in array functions including `array_unshift` which allows you to add an element to the beginning and `array_pop` which allows you to remove an element from the end:

```
array_unshift($foo, 'how'); // Add to the beginning
array_pop($foo); // Remove from the end
```

Example: https://eval.in/859692

Comment: Thanks for trying to help...  I want like this: (how >  what > whom)  but you code return (how > when > whom)......  i want to get data depend serial. Would you please help me....

Comment: I'm afraid I do not understand the logic. You said you want the "oldest" to be removed. How do you know that "what" is the oldest? I was under the impression if you are adding items to the beginning and removing from the end then the last item must be the "oldest" and should be removed?

Comment: I called oldest means first element which is "when".

Comment: Then why do "what" and "whom" change positions in the expected output array?

Comment: Thanks neuromatter for you hard trying to help me. But @Progrock will share a code which work perfectly...

Answer (score 0):

**The Fastest method You can Increase the More limit..**

```
$array = ['One' => 1, 'Two' => 2, 'Three' => 3, 'Four' => 4, 'Five' => 5];
//selecting First 3 Arrays
foreach (new LimitIterator(new ArrayIterator($array), 0, 3) as $key => $val)
{
  echo "$key => $val\n";
}
```

Give a Test

Comment: I test your code... This output reverse.  Would you tell me how can I get output without reverse... your output (two > three > four) but I want (four > three > two ).

Comment: Really? is that output two,three,four? i have tested that it shows One,two,three for me. :( it picks the 1st 3arrays... if add new array it will get the new and next 2 = 1st three arrays

Comment: I make one change.. First I tried your code.. It Output( One,two,three) but I user 1 Instead of 0 it output (two, three, four)

Comment: Could you Please give me the code what you have modified? let me test it

Comment: So you just need the last 3 array values? Use this to retrieve the last 3..

<?php
$a=array("One","Two","Three","Four","Five");
//print output
print_r(array_slice($a,-3));
?>

Comment: Thanks neuromatter for your hard trying to help me. But Progrock will share a code which work perfectly...

Comment: Abubakar this is Ajmal Praveen hope u got a working code

Answer (score 0):

PHP scripts are no persistent, so I would suggest using `time()` as a key for each value. Then you know which one was put in first, and just write a function to overwrite the oldest.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$queue        = [];
$queue_length = 3;

$add_item = function($item) use (&$queue, $queue_length) {
    array_unshift($queue, $item) &&
    count($queue) == $queue_length + 1 &&
    array_pop($queue);

    var_dump($queue);
};

$add_item('first');
$add_item('second');
$add_item('third');
$add_item('fourth');
$add_item('fifth');
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "first"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "second"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "first"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "third"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "second"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "first"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "fourth"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "third"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "second"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "fifth"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "fourth"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "third"
}
```